# Mathematical riddle

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

**Part one:**
You are presented with ten incomplete equations:

- 0 0 0 = 6
- 1 1 1 = 6
- 2 2 2 = 6
- 3 3 3 = 6
- 4 4 4 = 6
- 5 5 5 = 6
- 6 6 6 = 6
- 7 7 7 = 6
- 8 8 8 = 6
- 9 9 9 = 6

Your job is to fill in mathematical operators in order to make all equations true.

1. You can not connect two digits into one number. So for example you cannot connect two fives into fifty five. Each digit is it's own separate number.
2. You cannot add in more numbers, including in operators. So squaring is invalid, because in order to square you need to add in the number two. A square root is allowed, but not any other root that requires additional numbers.
3. A square root of a square root is a fourth root, which is also not allowed
4. You cannot change anything but the left side of the equation
5. Functions such as sine, tangent etc. Are not allowed.
6. Using ^ is not accepted

**Part two:**
using the same rules, can you fill in

- n n n n = 6

Comment: @boboquack I wasn't aware of this, but my version is a bit tweaked

Comment: @boboquack If it does count as a duplicate, do as you please

Comment: That comment was automatically generated by the system. My observation is that the only difference is part two - if you changed part two to be the whole question, it would be distinct enough, but at the moment most of the question is the same is the linked question.

Comment: The rules are also different

Comment: All the solutions in the accepted answer work here.

Comment: @boboquack true, but 8 - v(v(8+8) is also correct in the first one, and is not in mine.

Comment: The most extreme case has to be:(2^3)- v(v(2^3+2^3)) which some people have tried to suggest in real life, which is why it is a rule

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Part One:

> (0! + 0! + 0!)! = 6 
>  (1 + 1 + 1)! = 6 
>  2 + 2 + 2 = 6 
>  3! + 3! - 3! = 6 
>  4 + 4 - √4 = 6 
>  5 + (5 / 5) = 6 
>  6 + 6 - 6 = 6 
>  7 - (7 / 7) = 6 
>  (√(8 + (8 / 8)))! = 6 
>  (√9)! + (√9)! - (√9)! = 6

Part Two:

> ((n!/n!)+(n!/n!))# = 6 
> # is being used as Primorial, which is the product of the first x prime numbers. In this case, the first two primes, which is 2*3=6 
>  Alternatively: 
>  ((n! + n! + n!) / n!)! = 6

Comment: A. I said a square root of a square root is not allowed B. What about part two?

Comment: Try typing `√a` (√a) instead of `va` or even `$\sqrt a$` ($\sqrt a$).

Comment: second equation requires a correction as either of the below shown ways:  (1) (1 + 1 + 1) ! OR (2) (1! + 1! + 1!) ! but not the given one!

Comment: Thanks for spotting my slight error with the 1s, Mea. What about now, @Lavigo ?

Comment: If a primorial is going to be considered an invalid function, then so should a factorial, (primorial is just "prime factorial" in a way, hence the name) which makes the entire question impossible.

Comment: As far as I understand, your solution comes out as two. Am I misunderstanding anything?

Comment: I get it now. Well done, I did not think of that.

Comment: An alternative solution for part 2 to is to use the solution for part 1 and replace one of the numbers by $\sqrt{n*n}$. You would need to change the part 1 answer for 9 as the substitution would lead to a root of a root, but you could use $9-\sqrt{\sqrt{9}*\sqrt{9}} = 6$ for example.

Comment: It took me a while to think of it. The tricky part was trying to make an equation that would work for 0 as well as all other integers. I knew I'd have to use factorials, but then I also thought that might screw with larger numbers. Though now I think about it, I think ((n!+n!+n!)/n!)! would also work.

Comment: It doesn't say `n` has to be an integer, or from 0-9 (@Jaap). Also, I thought the primorial `p#` was the product of the primes less than or equal to `p`?

Comment: @boboquack That's what I thought too, but then I looked it up

Comment: Aha! But $p_5=11$ - so $p_5\#=11\#=2310$, which is what I said. Importantly, $p_1=2$, so $p_1\#=2\#=2$ (@Lavigo).

Comment: I copied the wrong bit. xD It is written in the first introduction section on Wikipedia it has two definitons and states them. I will admit I used the less-used of the two, but the puzzle did not say I was not allowed to.

Comment: @Timoris ((n!+n!+n!)/n!)! Was the one I was going for. edit it into your answer!

Comment: @Timoris Very true.

Comment: A * and a - is much simpler for 3.

Answer (score 3):

In continuation to earlier answer, here is one for part two:

> ((n+n+n)/n) ! = 6 for all n >0.

And if n = 0,

> ((n! + n! + n!))! * n! or ((n! + n! + n!))! / n!

And here is one more, perhaps

> ( log n (n * n *n ) )! that is log to the base n (subscript) of n cubed.

Comment: The previous answer was wrong though.

Comment: Division by 0 alert! Please deal with the special case.

Comment: Ok it was fixed now

Comment: The last one is the one I originally came up with. Well done.